# Looking for a statistical difference between two groups of ranked data

Tags: statistical-significance, ranking

I have data from two different ethnic groups (not same sample size...) ranking different traits. Each group rank ordered the 10 different traits, and I want to test to see if there is a difference between the way they ranked the data. Is there a test I can use to test whether the rankings are different overall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be looking for what has sometimes been called ANACONDA. See this [paper](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/62/2/417.abstract) by Li and Schucany entitled "Some properties of a test for concordance of two groups of rankings" and then a subsequent [one](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/65/2/403.abstract) by Hollander and Sethuraman entitled "Testing for agreement between two groups of judges"

Suppose that one group has $m$ rankings with ranks $R_{ij}$ $(i = 1, ...,m; j = 1, ..., k)$ and that the other group has $n$ rankings with ranks $R^{'}_{ij}$  $(i = 1, ..., n; j = 1, .. ., k)$. Let $$S_j = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} R_{ij},\quad T_j = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} R^{'}_{ij}$$ the statistic $\mathcal{L}$ is defined to be $\sum_{i=1}^k S_j T_j$.

Li and Schucany then discuss how to derive its distribution.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!