# Friedman test for rank order question - Comparing between groups

Tags: r, friedman-test

In my study, participants ranked a total of 5 designs (different lamp types) in their order of preference (absolute favourite, second favourite, etc.). Participants ranked all lamps, and lamps were presented in random order to participants. Participants could not give the same rank to two lamps. I now want to evaluate whether there are any differences in the participant preferences. My second step will be to test whether there are any differences between male / female participants.

To answer my initial question, I believe a Friedman Test is appropriate. As far as I understood, Friedman would transform my data to rank data (which it already is, as participants have indicated their preference order). As shown in the code below, using both 'raw' numeric values and 'ranked' numeric values (done manually by me) produce the same Friedman Test results. I previously made an error in creating the ranked table, but the code below showcases that the comparison between raw and ranked values produces identical results.

My question now focuses on the comparison between two groups (e.g., man/woman) in their lamp (order) preference. I'd like to know whether there is a significant difference between participant groups in their preference, but have no idea how to tackle this. Imagine that the group (e.g., gender) is an additional column in the dataframe.

I came across the Scheirer-Ray-Hare test online, although the test does not seem to be universally accepted. Thank you very much in advance for your time!

--

```
# load data. Letters are lamp designs (columns), numbers are individual participants (rows)
y <- structure(c(3.88, 5.64, 5.76, 4.25, 5.91, 4.33, 30.58, 30.14, 
16.92, 23.19, 26.74, 10.91, 25.24, 33.52, 25.45, 18.85, 20.45, 
26.67, 4.44, 7.94, 4.04, 4.4, 4.23, 4.36, 29.41, 30.72, 32.92, 
28.23, 23.35, 12, 38.87, 33.12, 39.15, 28.06, 38.23, 26.65), .Dim = c(6L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F")))

y_ranked <- structure(c(6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 
1, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), .Dim = c(6L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F")))


friedman.test(y)
> Friedman chi-squared = 23.333, df = 5, p-value = 0.0002915

friedman.test(y_ranked)
> Friedman chi-squared = 23.333, df = 5, p-value = 0.0002915
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run in a clean session; i.e. your example is NOT reproducible (*reproducible* means if I paste your code then what I see *reproduces* what you see). R does not come with a function called `freidmanTest`. Whatever package it's from (scmamp? PMCMRplus? something else?), try reading the help on that function (which should include examples for you to follow). However, R does come with a test called `friedman.test` and the example in the help there shows the two main ways to call it (the last two lines), each matching the calling syntax given at the top of the `friedman.test` help

Comment: Having trouble making sense of what you're doing and asking: Please clarify-- (1) Are the letters A, B, C, ... the Groups (lamp designs) and the numbers 1, 2, 3, ... the Participants? Is that 5 or 6 of each? (2) Can you clarify exactly how you got matrix `z` from matrix `y`---with a row or col as an example to show it's right? (3) Do you know the difference btw `friedman.test` and `friedmanTest`? Does your test procedure expect matrix columns to be Groups or Participants?

Comment: @Glen_b Apologies, I tested both base-R and PMCMRplus Friedman test, have now changed my code back to base-R and it should be reproducible. Sorry for the oversight on my part.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: @BruceET, I have now updated my question to hopefully clarify this.
I am mostly interested in (2), how to evaluate between two different groups - but would also like to understand the difference between two identically 'ranked' groups (1). Thank you very much!

Comment: Your ranks don't seem to relate to the original data. Please explain how you got them.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you Glen - you were absolutely right. I made an error in calculating the ranks of my data, and after fixing this error the test produces the expected result! Now I'm left wondering how to best compare between groups.

Comment: I think you may be looking for a technique called ANACONDA. See my answer to a similar question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251691/looking-for-a-statistical-difference-between-two-groups-of-ranked-data/251775#251775

Comment: @Walter You can probably remove question 1; it seems like it was perhaps a coding issue after all; it may be best to focus on the other question. For question 2, can you clearly identify what 'groups' you mean? Do you mean the male vs female comparison?

Comment: @mdewey Thank you. Is there by any chance an R package available to use with ANACONDA? Googling for R + ANACONDA is quite challenging given the name of related software packages. I also wonder how valid ANACONDA is for non-parametric data? Thanks!

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you, I've updated my original question as this was indeed 'simply' a coding issue from my side. Hopefully someone can answer my remaining question.

Comment: I do not know of any R package. Calculating the statistic is fairly easy but unless you can rely on asymptotic normality going beyond that is harder. It is suitable for rankings so if you can rank your data you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Friedman's test is an appropriate approach to answer the first question.  And, yes, I would avoid the Scheirer-Ray-Hare test.  It appears to not be well regarded from a theoretical standpoint, but also in my experience it  will fail to find a significant interaction effect in cases where other tests will find one. For a model more complex than can be handled by Friedman or Kruskal-Wallis, you might look into aligned ranks transformation (ART) anova. The [ARTool software](http://depts.washington.edu/ilab/proj/art/index.html) for R and Windows makes the process relatively easy, but be sure to read the complete documentation. For example, all interactions should be included in the model, and handling post-hoc comparisons of interactions can be tricky. ART anova is a rank based method and allows for relatively complex models including repeated measures. Below I've given you the code of a possible model. There are some resources for ART at the bottom of [this page](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/F_16.html), that you may want to review.  (Caveat: I am the author of that page.) (At the time of writing this R code will run at [rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/snippets/)).

```
### Load data. Letters are lamp designs (columns), 
###  numbers are individual participants (rows)

y <- structure(c(3.88, 5.64, 5.76, 4.25, 5.91, 4.33, 30.58, 30.14, 
16.92, 23.19, 26.74, 10.91, 25.24, 33.52, 25.45, 18.85, 20.45, 
26.67, 4.44, 7.94, 4.04, 4.4, 4.23, 4.36, 29.41, 30.72, 32.92, 
28.23, 23.35, 12, 38.87, 33.12, 39.15, 28.06, 38.23, 26.65), .Dim = c(6L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F")))

y

### Transform data to long format

Data = reshape(as.data.frame(y), varying = LETTERS[1:6], 
       timevar = "Lamp", v.names="Score",
       times = LETTERS[1:6], 
       direction = 'long')

Data$Gender[Data$id==1]="Female"
Data$Gender[Data$id==2]="Female"
Data$Gender[Data$id==3]="Female"
Data$Gender[Data$id==4]="Male"
Data$Gender[Data$id==5]="Male"
Data$Gender[Data$id==6]="Male"

Data$Lamp   = factor(Data$Lamp)
Data$Gender = factor(Data$Gender)
Data$id     = factor(Data$id)

Data


### ART anova

if(!require(ARTool)){install.packages("ARTool")}
library(ARTool)

model = art(Score ~ Lamp + Gender + Lamp:Gender,
                data = Data)

anova(model)

### Post-hoc comparisons
### Be sure to read documentation about this topic.

model.lm = artlm(model, "Lamp")

if(!require(emmeans)){install.packages("emmeans")}
library(emmeans)

marginal = emmeans(model.lm, ~ Lamp)

CLD(marginal, adjust = "tukey", Letters=letters)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was I looking for, thank you very much! Really appreciated.