# Comparing two groups based on how they ranked items

Tags: r, ranking

In a survey on Qualtrics, I have asked two groups (Group A and Group B) to rank their preferred mode of communication: "list the following modes of communication in order of your preference, drag and drop the most attractive on top to the least attractive on the bottom: portal-based; videoconference; phone; in-person; email)".

Data look like the following.

| subject | Group | portal-based | videoconference | phone | in-person | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | B | 3 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | A | 5 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | B | 4 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 5 | A | 1 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 2 |
| 6 | B | 5 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 3 |

Using R, I need to compare Group A and B in terms of a) whether Group A and Group B ranked communication modes significantly different. b) whether distribution of each single item differs significantly between Groups A and B.

Any advice on the type of test and the code is highly appreciated.

PS: I have seen this. It is not specifically applicable to my case. [Friedman test for rank order question - Comparing between groups](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422858/friedman-test-for-rank-order-question-comparing-between-groups)

Comment: If you could say why you think Friedman test is inappropriate, it may help to find a useful method.

Comment: My understanding is that Friedman answers the question 'whether any of the methods ranked consistently higher or lower than the others in the total sample'. I do not think it is appropriate to answer 'whether Group A and Group B ranked methods significantly different'.